# What does "coarse" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Roberto poured wine into a **coarse** glass.

L. Scottoline "Loyalty"

(Roberto is a farmhand in a lemon grove, Sicily, 1810)

can "coarse" here mean "simple"? Or, maybe, "textured"?

Comment: Roughly made, cheap, not refined or stylish. The kind of glass a peasant would have.

Comment: Not elegantly finished, polished, and expensive.

Comment: Probably like his wine: not fine.

Comment: You should indicate the results of your research. Are "simple" and "textured" words that you found as synonyms for "coarse"? If so, where did you find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably like his wine: not fine. Roughly made, cheap, not refined or stylish. Not elegantly finished, polished, and expensive. The kind of glass a peasant would have.

Comment: converting answer comments to cw